# some ideas of how export a hymn to XML without losing the position of chords

Tags: android, xml, music-notation

I created a program to move from PDF to XML, but for some reason the chords change places unlike the original. I wanted to ask to see if you give me any idea to help me. I'm a bit stuck

Actualy this is my xml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
android:orientation='vertical'
android:layout_width='match_parent'
 android:layout_height='match_parent' >
<TextView 
android:layout_width='wrap_content'
android:layout_height='wrap_content'
android:fontFamily='sans-serif' 
android:typeface='serif' 
android:textAppearance='?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge'
android:text=' G      C  G  G   C  Em             D                     C                          G               ' android:textSize='15sp' />
<TextView 
android:layout_width='wrap_content'
android:layout_height='wrap_content'
android:fontFamily='sans-serif' 
android:typeface='serif' 
android:textAppearance='?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge'
android:text='¡Aleluya, aleluya! Te alabamos, Señor, nuestro Rey.  '     android:textSize='18sp' />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oehED.png)
and my final result in [android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpLW5.png)

I tried changing the font size, change of position but always wrong.
I want to use text no images.

Thanks for your help